# Code inspection is not working! Intellij IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-inspections

I am having problems with intellijs Ultimate code inspection! 
It is only showing me the basic inspection/alternatives for code replacement like "Invert if condition" and nothing else.
I have checked on the preferences if everything is selected and I also reinstalled intellij but still not working!

It used to give me more alternatives for code replacement not only the "Invert if condition" but there were more alternatives. One of them was 
"Replace Optional.isPresent() condition with functional style expression"

So whenever I wrote :

```
  if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(userOptional.get());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).
            body(new ErrorMessage("User " + id + " was not found"));
```

... it used to give me this kind of replacement:

```
 return userOptional.<ResponseEntity<?>>map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .orElseGet(()->ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
            .body(new ErrorMessage("User " + id + " was not found")));
```

Comment: Thanks. I am speaking about code inspection/replacment that intellij offer and  not about simpifying the code. I just gave this code snippet as an example.

Comment: what inspection are you expecting to run with the given code?

Comment: Intellijs inspection. It used to give me alternatives such as the example above.i mean intellij inspect the code and then it gives me alternatives like : this code can be replaced with ....

Comment: ..and then? it doesn't compile? Please do edit your question with the details.

Comment: ok maybe now you will get it!

Comment: Hopefully, the IDE inspection developers realized that the suggestion as you described wasn't good at all. Worth mentioning the versions of IntelliJ when you use to get the suggestions versus the version when you don't get it. Or any other inspection configuration that you might remember changing.

Comment: Please don't add the functional programming tag to questions not about functional programming.

Comment: Can you please provide the full code sample with dependencies where the inspection used to work, but now doesn't. After installation of what version have you started experiencing the change of behaviour?